# Broken line at joins in opengl on iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, drawing, line

I am using cocos2d to draw custom shapes for a game. I have an array of polygon points that I use to plot the border of a polygon using the below opengl code.

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glLineWidth(4);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, polyVertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, polyVertexCount);
```

However, I get this result ([**LINK**](http://i96.photobucket.com/albums/l199/maulik13/broken-curves.png)) on simulator.

It seems that the problem is where the line segments are supposed to join. How do I solve this? What are the options to create different join types in opengl es? Is there any drawing library I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line width in OpenGL does not allow for the miter between contiguous lines to join with one another. So if you have a line that goes up which is connected to a line that goes left, there will be a very obvious discontinuity if the line width is > 1.

If you're serious about line drawing with line width, and you need the miters to join, then you need to not use OpenGL's line drawing. You need to create a polygonal mesh that represents what you're trying to draw and do the miter computations yourself.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This confirms what direction I need to head towards. So if I create a polygonal mesh such that I can fill it with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP will be the start right?